# excel TODAY function to string yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, formatting

**I have this formula with a hard-coded string that I want to concatenate with today's date but output as we often write dates in Europe `(yyyy-mm-dd)`
Formula**

`=CONCAT("2021-10-01"; " > ";TEXT(TODAY();"YYYY-MM-DD"))`

**I expected**

`2021-10-01 > 2022-06-18`

**But get this:**

`2021-10-01 > YYYY-06-18`

**If I troubleshoot with YY, yyyy, Y it's no difference.
If I simplify the formula to just use today function, not combining with text function:**

`=CONCAT("2021-10-01"; " > ";TODAY())`

**I get what I expect a serial**

`2021-10-01 > 44730`

Comment: Judging by the semicolons `;` your language is set to a different one. This can result in having to reference the year differently. In my language (Dutch) for instance it would be `"jjjj-mm-dd"`

Comment: Right click on a cell =>`Format Cells`=>`Custom` and scroll down until you see the date format codes. Those will show what the token is for year.  (*If this worksheet needs to be internationally aware, you will need vba*)

Comment: Can you give a try on `=CONCAT("2021-10-01"; " > ";TEXT(TODAY();"e-mm-dd"))`

Answer (score 0):

Hi all and thanks for the respons. Sending this to the TEXT function did it.
"e-mm-dd"

This format things are always tricky to find out.