# Converting excel dates from mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I am currently using this formula to convert dates from mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy

```
=DATE(VALUE(RIGHT(F47433,4)),VALUE(LEFT(F47433,FIND("/",F47433)-1)),VALUE(MID(F47433,FIND("/",F47433)+1,2)))
```

It works for the most part but it errors when there is a single digit for both day and month. it gives a #VALUE error.

example
I want to convert 9/1/2023 to the 01/09/2023 but it errors.

Any solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

**sample data**
[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/72666999/4961700

Comment: Thanks @SolarMike, but that isn't the date format I want

Comment: Maybe use `Text To Columns` instead of formulae

Comment: @JvdV I've tried that approach but no luck unfortunately.

Comment: I linked to that for the method...

Comment: @PythonBeginner what did you use for dates while using `Text To Columns` if you are using `MDY` try using `DMY` and check what difference do you get.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya when I use Text to Columns, nothing happens I have tried MDY, DMY, YMD

Comment: @PythonBeginner have you imported those dates from any external applications? Like `SAP` or any `Oracle Applications`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Yes I have

Comment: @PythonBeginner honestly speaking dates and times are very tricky, could you upload a sample workbook so that i can look into it as well may be others who are interested as well, may try to find a solution for you

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya stackoverflow doesn't give an option to upload but I have uploaded a screenshot of my excel, the left column are the dates I'm attempting to format

Comment: @PythonBeginner but you can link a `One-Drive` or a `GS` i only asked because, with screenshot we cannot determine whether its possible with `Text-To-Columns` or not also, due to regional settings it varies, i will try to find a way.

Comment: @PythonBeginner could you try out this one, it worked for me, `=DATE(RIGHT(TEXT(A1,"mm/dd/yyyy"),4),LEFT(TEXT(A1,"mm/dd/yyyy"),2),MID(TEXT(A1,"mm/dd/yyyy"),4,2))` assuming the dates are in cell A1 kindly suit the cell reference as per your data

Comment: @PythonBeginner or may be this one as well, `=TEXTJOIN("/",,MID(TEXT(A1,"mm/dd/yyyy"),{4,1,7},{2,2,4}))+0` and format as specific date format since this will return a number

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya unforunately those formulas are outputting mm/dd/yyyy still. heres  a link to the dataset https://onedrive.live.com/edit.aspx?resid=4A09A7BCF0AEAF11!105&ithint=file%2cxlsx

Comment: @PythonBeginner link says `This item might not exist or is no longer available`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya How about this https://1drv.ms/x/s!AhGvrvC8pwlKaQCgXNrSVDOsijw?e=zhlkTG

Comment: @PythonBeginner i saw there is something wrong in the sheet could you check cell A3736 please why is there a dropdown in between also found `MDY` using `Text To Columns` did work

Comment: @PythonBeginner updated, please check [Dates](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AhGvrvC8pwlKaQCgXNrSVDOsijw?e=tzCaQv)

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya apologies, the dropdown was as a result of a filter, when you do Text to columns what steps do you follow? I highlight the column, go to text to columns -> Delimited -> untick all boxes -> select date -> DMY

Comment: @PythonBeginner no need to apologise, i just asked what was that for, perhaps follow • Select the range, • First Step Delimited --> Next, • Second Step --> Next • Third Step --> Check on Date and change to `MDY` and Finish

Comment: Can you use `=TEXT(Field,"DD/MM/YYYY")`?

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is due to the system date format and excel file date format difference.
you can handle this problem by few ways.

1. Import the data into new excel file from the Menu: Data > Get Data > From File > From Excel
2. Copy the date column and paste in the notepad then copy it back to the excel.
3. change your pc date format [image: Like this]